# Restriction for invocation of constexpr constructor in a constant initializer

Tags: c++

I don't understand the following addition for `constexpr constructor` invocation:

> A constant initializer for an object o is an expression that is a
>   constant expression, except that it may also invoke **constexpr**
>   **constructors** for o and its subobjects even if those objects are of
>   non-literal class types

Constexpr constructor is core constant expression itself:

> A conditional-expression e is a core constant expression unless the
>   evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine (1.9),
>   would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> [...]
>
> — an invocation
>   of a function **other than a constexpr constructor** for a literal class,
>   a constexpr function, or an implicit invocation of a trivial
>   destructor (12.4)[...]

Comment: No time to read into the details now, but it could have to do with the "core constant expression" vs. "constant expression" distinction.

Comment: @Angew It would be interesting if you provide constexpt constructor invocation which is not a constant expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a substantial hint in the subsequent note:

> *[ Note: such a class may have a non-trivial destructor — end note ]*

Recall that a literal class type (3.9p10):

> - has a trivial destructor,
> - is an aggregate type (8.5.1) or has at least one constexpr constructor or constructor template that is not a copy or move constructor, and
> - all of its non-static data members and base classes are of non-volatile literal types.

Thus if a class has a non-trivial destructor it is disqualified from being a literal class, but an invocation of its constexpr constructor may still qualify as a constant initializer:

```
#include <iostream>
struct A {
    int count = 0;
    constexpr A() {}
    ~A() { std::cout << "~A: " << count << std::endl; }
};
A a;
```

The program can then rely on `a` being initialized before any dynamic initialization takes place, even though `A` is not a literal class type.

The *rationale* for this is that although `A`'s destructor has side effects, it is not called during initialization, so it is possible for the compiler to calculate the appropriate initial memory contents of `a` (in practical terms, its `.data`) at compile time.

---

Note that your emphasis in the second quote is incomplete; the relevant term is "*a constexpr constructor **for a literal class***".

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for exhaustive answer.